# Creating jQuery Deferred objects using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I am having a hard time understanding the value of creating your own Deferred object.

Say you have the following jQuery

```
    function doStuffFirst() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        // do some stuff here
        setTimeout(function() {
           dfd.resolve();
        },1);
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    function doStuffAfter() {
       //do some other stuff
    }

    $.when(doStuffFirst()).done(doStuffAfter);
```

I don't actually know that `doStuffFirst()` has finished, its just waiting some time before firing `doStuffAfter()`

why is that any better than just going

```
   function doStuffFirst() {
       // do some stuff here
   }

   setTimeout(function() {
      //do some other stuff
   },1);
```

Comment: The point of promises / deferreds is to encapsulate work in a function.  If you don't have any work to do, they're useless.

Answer (score 1):

You do know that it is finished; but it is useless as it stands, since you're not executing your task asynchronously. The task executes, then the deferred gets created and fired almost immediately. However, if you change to this:

```
function doStuffFirst() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do some stuff HERE
        dfd.resolve();
    },1);
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

then it becomes useful, since it will return immediately, but resolve some time later (whenever the task is done). While you have just one async task, using a deferred is not much different than using a plain callback (just more complex, and prettier, and the dependency goes the other way: callbacks go *in*, while promises come *out* of the routine that schedules the task). However, if you have more complex requirements, like having *two* async tasks which you want to execute simultaneously but wait until both are done, promises are much superior.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` simply executes the code after the given time, whereas promises executes code once the promised task has completed. Promises are used when dealing with things in which completion time is unknown, such as ajax requests. In `setTimeout`, you know when exactly to execute some code.